# Getting next value from sequence

Tags: java, sql

I have a bit of code here to get the next value of my sequence, but it is adding the total number of records onto the result each time.

I'm only learning about prepared Statements,  I'm thinking this is something small, maybe rset.next() should be something else?

```
public void add( String title, String actor, String genre ) {
    try {
        String sql2 = "Select movie_seq.nextval from Movie";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

            rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
            int nextVal = 0;
            if(rset.next())
                nextVal = rset.getInt(1);



        String queryString = "Select MovieID, Title, Actor, Genre from Movie";
        pstmt = conn
                .prepareStatement(queryString,
                        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rset = pstmt.executeQuery();

        rset.moveToInsertRow();
        rset.updateInt(1, nextVal);
        rset.updateString(2, title);
        rset.updateString(3, actor);
        rset.updateString(4, genre);
        rset.insertRow();
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        System.out.println("Error going to previous row");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the call to `pstmt.executeUpdate();`

As stated in [ResultSet doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#insertRow%28%29), the function insertRow stores the row in the Dataset AND in the database.

The following code shows all that's necessary to add a new row:

```
   rset.moveToInsertRow(); // moves cursor to the insert row
   rset.updateString(1, "AINSWORTH"); // updates the
      // first column of the insert row to be AINSWORTH
   rset.updateInt(2,35); // updates the second column to be 35
   rset.updateBoolean(3, true); // updates the third column to true
   rset.insertRow();
   rset.moveToCurrentRow();
```

Comment: That peace of code works fine.
its just this peace I'm having an issue with:


    String sql2 = "Select movie_seq.nextval from Movie";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

            rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
            int nextVal = 0;
            if(rset.next())
                nextVal = rset.getInt(1);

Comment: Couldn't you just write: sql2 = "INSERT INTO Movie 
        (MovieID, Title, Actor, Genre ) VALUES 
        (movie_seq.nextval,?,?,?)";    ? With this statement you could avoid the two select statements and the movetoinsertrow .

Comment: Yeah I could, but I have to do it this way for college.

Comment: so what does your result look like?

Comment: I already have 8 records inserted in the table using sql2 = "INSERT INTO Movie (MovieID, Title, Actor, Genre ) VALUES (movie_seq.nextval,?,?,?)"; 

So the nextval is 9.

It works the first time and the next record is inserted with MovieID as 9.

But the nextval jumps to 17, 
then the nextval jumps to 26.

Comment: Ok. That's no error that's more or less expected behavior. I'm not sure about that but I think those jumps come from the cache (whose size you can specify upon creation). You can't expect Oracle Sequences not to contain gaps.

Comment: Really, so there is no way to do it the way I want? 
What would specifying the cache size achieve?

Comment: Specifying the cache size would lead to smaller gaps I guess. To avoid the gaps you could create the sequence like so: CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;    as it's stated here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF54256

Comment: I've already created my sequence like that, I could be wrong, but I suspect something else is happing here, the number it jumps by is the amount of records in the table + the nextval number.
Defiantly seems like something could stop the records number being added onto the nextval number, thus giving me the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you iterate using while rather than if . something like this

```
List lst = new ArrayList();

Someclass sc = new SomeClass(); //object of the class 

    String query = "SELECT * from SomeTable";
                PreparedStatement pstmt = sqlConn.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                Role role = null;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String one = rs.getString(1);
                    String two = rs.getString(2);
                    boolean  three = rs.getBoolean(3);
                    //if you have setters getters for them 
                               sc.setOne(one);
                               sc.setTwo(two);
                               sc,setThree(three);
                           lst.add(sc)
                                    }
//in the end return lst which is of type List<SomeClass>
            }
```

Comment: or if you are trying to read a list create a list of the class type like List<someclass> and add these objects to that list

Comment: I have to get the next value of my sequence.

Comment: you can create a new instance each time and add this to a list .

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing this instead?:

```
String sql2 = "Select " + movie_seq.nextval + " from Movie";
```

As it is, it seems like you're passing a slightly bogus string into the SQL query, which is probably defaulting to the max index (not 100% positive on that). Then rs.next() is just incrementing that.

Comment: movie_seq.nextval is not a variable.

Comment: Ah, my SQL rustiness is showing. I guess I'm confused by what you mean by adding to the result.